# Use of unresolved identifier 'FUIEmailAuth'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm currently teaching myself Swift so any help would be great. I wanted to integrate a `Firebase` Email Login into my app, but I keep receiving this error preventing me from running my app. Any suggestions would be a life saver!

I have searched and searched the web and couldn't find any solution

```
  // Set ourselves as the delegate
        authUI?.delegate = self
        authUI?.providers = [FUIEmailAuth]() // ERROR here
```

> Error: Use of unresolved identifier 'FUIEmailAuth'

Comment: Welcome to SO. It looks like your pod file may not be complete or installed correctly, please include it in your question. Secondly, there's not enough code to know what your attempting to do - Email address and password authentication, email link? something else? The [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/firebaseui#email_address_and_password) is straightforward so work through that. Since you're new take a look [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Oh, and the link with basic email and password documentation is [Email & Password Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth) and a really great place to start since it's super simple and a short amount of code.