# Use of unresolved identifier 'FUIEmailAuth'FUIEmailAuth

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

I'm making a login screen using firebase auth UI and swift.

When I run the app, currently it only shows a welcome screen like this [welcome screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLrk4.png).
But I want to display the page the firebase prebuilt UI with a text field that a user can type their email address, something like this. [login-with email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Oyhl.png)

Here is my current code.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseUI


class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


//MARK: - sign in / sign up

@IBAction func playPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
            
    let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()
    
    guard authUI != nil else {
        return
    }
    
    authUI?.delegate = self
    authUI?.providers = [FUIEmailAuth()]

    
    let authViewController = authUI!.authViewController()
    
    
    present(authViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

}

extension ViewController: FUIAuthDelegate{
func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith authDataResult: AuthDataResult?, error: Error?) {
    
    if error != nil {
        return

    }
    
    
    performSegue(withIdentifier: K.loginSegue, sender: self)
}
}
```

and I get error on the code written as "authUI?.providers = [FUIEmailAuth()]". The error message is

> Use of unresolved identifier 'FUIEmailAuth'FUIEmailAuth

I saw some other people run into the same problem, and I tried pod update, but I still get the error message.

Also, on [the firebase document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/firebaseui), they use 'FUIEmailAuth' in their sample code, so I wonder why I'm getting that error and how to fix it.

Comment: same question in this link, but this doesn't help..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56204812/use-of-unresolved-identifier-fuiemailauth

Answer (score 0):

I just add pod 'FirebaseUI/Email' in my pod file and it solved the problem.